# Remove table inline style using PHP

Tags: php, html, html-table

Is there an easy way to remove inline styles and attributes from a table using PHP.

For example, remove class, style, width, height from code below:

```
<tr class=xl96 height=30 style='mso-height-source:userset;height:23.1pt'>
<td height=30 class=xl99 style='height:23.1pt;border-top:none'>9</td>
<td class=xl100 style='border-top:none;border-left:none'>46333</td>
<td class=xl101 style='border-top:none;border-left:none'>&yen;698</td>
<td class=xl99 style='border-top:none;border-left:none'>48</td>
<td class=xl100 style='border-top:none;border-left:none'>2077988</td>
<td class=xl101 style='border-top:none;border-left:none'>&yen;698</td>
<td class=xl98></td>
<td class=xl96></td>
<td class=xl96></td>
</tr>
```

Expected Result:

```
<tr>
<td>9</td>
<td>46333</td>
<td>&yen;698</td>
<td>48</td>
<td>2077988</td>
<td>&yen;698</td>
<td></td>
<td></td>
<td></td>
</tr>
```

Comment: You can put that html in a string and parse through it, or you appended some javascript that does that for you. Or you Define new css with the !important Attribute to override the inline styles

Comment: please explain better - how you get this html, from where? (your code prints it out, you are parsing some page, etc, etc...)?

Comment: why not just do it by css ?

Comment: @nevermind the code converted from Excel file.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
$doc = new DOMDocument(); 
$doc->loadHTML($html); 

foreach($doc->getElementsByTagName('*') as $node) 
{ 
    $node->removeAttribute('height'); 
    $node->removeAttribute('style'); 
    $node->removeAttribute('class');
} 

$doc->removeChild($doc->firstChild);
$doc->replaceChild($doc->firstChild->firstChild->firstChild, $doc->firstChild);

echo $doc->saveHTML();
```

Output

```
<tr><td>9</td> <td>46333</td> <td>&yen;698</td> <td>48</td> <td>2077988</td> 
<td>&yen;698</td> <td></td> <td></td> <td></td> </tr>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$yourVariable= preg_replace('#(<[a-z ]*)(style=("|\')(.*?)("|\'))([a-z ]*>)#', '\\1\\6', $yourVariable);
```

try it

Answer (score 0):

The only way I can imagine this would work is either this:

```
<?php 
    $styles = ' style="border-top:none;border-left:none;"';

    echo '<tr class=xl96 height=30 style='mso-height-source:userset;height:23.1pt'>
              <td height=30 class=xl99 style='height:23.1pt;border-top:none'>9</td>
              <td class=xl100'.$style.'>46333</td>
              <td class=xl101'.$style.'>&yen;698</td>
              <td class=xl99'.$style.'>48</td>
              <td class=xl100'.$style.'>2077988</td>
              <td class=xl101'.$style.'>&yen;698</td>
              <td class=xl98></td>
              <td class=xl96></td>
              <td class=xl96></td>
          </tr>


?>
```

or using regex.

Answer (score 0):

Or you append this to your css:

```
Table
{ 
    border-top:auto !important;
    border-left:auto !important; 
    Height:auto !important; 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This regular expresion replace all elements properties with just empty tag.
To ilustrate how this expresion work I used Sublime Text 3 text editor.

First round brackets selects `<` char and **first word** with `\w+`. This is our `$1`. Then we just need to selet evrything up to `>` and replace it with `<$1>`. Very simple. You can use php preg_replace function for that.

```
<(\w+)
```

[image]

**Find:**

```
<(\w+).*?>
```

**Replace:**

```
<$1>
```

Before:
[image]
After:
[image]